# joint state publisher dies, cannot attach wheels with continuous joint

Tags: joint, urdf, ros-melodic, ubuntu, joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently trying to create a simple differential drive robot model with 2 wheels and 2 caster wheels, but I cannot attach the wheels to the chassis with continuous/revolute joints and I do not get the transforms of course, but I can connect them with fixed joints and I also get the correct transforms with the fixed joints.

I am using ros melodic with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on VM 6.0.12

- /rosdistro: melodic
- /rosversion: 1.14.3

Here is the error message I get:

Error Message

```
SUMMARY

PARAMETERS 
* /joint_state_publisher/use_gui: True 
* /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
* /rosdistro: melodic
* /rosversion: 1.14.3

NODES 
/ joint_state_publisher (joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)
 robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher) 
 rviz (rviz/rviz)

auto-starting new master 
process[master]: started with pid [18519] 
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 2a1bb272-f0b9-11e9-b0ed-080027935df5 
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [18530] 
started core service [/rosout] 
process[joint_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [18533] 
process[robot_state_publisher-3]: started with pid [18538] 
process[rviz-4]: started with pid [18539] 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher", line 474, in jsp = JointStatePublisher() 
File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher", line 149, in init robot = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(description) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1928, in parseString return expatbuilder.parseString(string) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 940, in parseString return builder.parseString(string) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString parser.Parse(string, True) 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u202c' in position 5988: ordinal not in range(128) [joint_state_publisher-2] process has died [pid 18533, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher __name:=joint_state_publisher __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/2a1bb272-f0b9-11e9-b0ed-080027935df5/joint_state_publisher-2.log]. log file: /home/user/.ros/log/2a1bb272-f0b9-11e9-b0ed-080027935df5/joint_state_publisher-2*.log
```

URDF file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="mybot">
  
  <link name="base_footprint"/>

  <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_footprint"/>
    <child link="chassis" />
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.010" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="chassis">
    <collision name="base_collision">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.35"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1 1.8 0.4"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="base_visual">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.35"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1 1.8 0.4"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision name="l_side_collision">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.475 0 1.18"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.05 1.8 2.0"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="l_side_visual">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.475 0 1.18"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.05 1.8 2.0"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision name="r_side_long_collision">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.475 0.45 1.18"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.05 0.9 2.0"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="r_side_long_visual">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.475 0.45 1.18"/>  
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.05 0.9 2.0"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision name="r_side_short_collision">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.475 -0.45 0.68"/>
      <geometry>  
        <box size="0.05 0.9 1.0"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="r_side_short_visual">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.475 -0.45 0.68"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.05 0.9 1.0"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision name="l_lidar_sup_collision">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.45 -0.95 1.2"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.025"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="l_lidar_sup_visual">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.45 -0.95 1.2"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.025"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision name="r_lidar_sup_collision">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.45 0.95 1.2"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.025"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="r_lidar_sup_visual">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.45 0.95 1.2"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.025"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision name="roof_collision">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 2.18"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1 1.8 0.05"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="roof_visual">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 2.18"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1 1.8 0.05"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision name='caster_collision_front'>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 -0.72 0.17"/>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius=".18"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name='caster_visual_front'>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 -0.72 0.17"/>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius=".18"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision name='caster_collision_back'>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0.72 0.17"/>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius=".18"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name='caster_visual_back'>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0.72 0.17"/>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius=".18"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <link name="l_wheel">
    <collision name="l_wheel_collision">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.025"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.18" length="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="l_wheel_visual">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.025"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.18" length="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red"/>
    </visual>
  </link>
  
  <link name="r_wheel">
    <collision name="r_wheel_collision">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.025"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.18" length="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="r_wheel_visual">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.025"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.18" length="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="green"/>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint type="revolute" name="l_wheel_hinge">
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="l_wheel"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <origin rpy="0 1.57 0" xyz="-0.5 0 0.17"/>
    <limit lower="-0.2" upper="0.2" effort="0.1" velocity="0.005"/>
  </joint>

  <joint type="revolute" name="r_wheel_hinge">
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="r_wheel"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <origin rpy="0 1.57 0" xyz="0.5 0 0.17"/>
    <limit lower="-0.2" upper="0.2" effort="0.1" velocity="0.005"/>
  </joint>

</robot>
```

Launch- File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch>
 <!-- USE: roslaunch min_examp urdf_visualize.launch model:='$(find min_examp)/urdf/myrobot.urdf'-->
   <arg name="model" default=""/>
   
   <param name="robot_description" command="cat $(arg model)"/>
   <!--param name="robot_description" command="cat $(arg urdf_robot_file)"/-->

   <!-- send fake joint values -->
   <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
     <param name="use_gui" value="TRUE"/>
   </node>

   <!-- combine joint vlues -->
   <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher"/>

   <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz"/>
</launch>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335574/joint-state-publisher-dies,-cannot-attach-wheels-with-continuous-joint/) by [chillbird](https://answers.ros.org/users/47369/chillbird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2019-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's very likely this has nothing to do with `continuous` or `fixed` joints:

> ```
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u202c' in position 5988: ordinal not in range(128)
> ```

`\u202c` is (according to [this random unicode website](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/index.htm)) a "*POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING*" character.

And it goes on to mention that this character is often used in `.pdf` files.

Did you by any chance copy some limits or other pieces of text from a `.pdf` into your `.urdf`?

If so, that is most likely where the problem is.

It's all parsed as ASCII text, so you'll need to make sure there are no extended or UTF characters in your `.urdf`. Otherwise, you'll get (variants) of the error message you posted.

---

Edit: according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001177), you could use the following `pgrep` command to search for the non-ASCII characters:

```
grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" /path/to/your/file.urdf
```

or:

```
grep --color='auto' -P -n "[^\x00-\x7F]" /path/to/your/file.urdf
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chillbird](https://answers.ros.org/users/47369/chillbird/) on 2019-10-17**:
thank soo much!